# To "sheet home"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms

From the (Australian) ABC news website:

> [Zombie microbes, reindeer and the health risks of climate change](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-08-02/bambrick-zombie-microbes-reindeer-and-climate-change-health-risk/7683078)
>
> An outbreak of anthrax in Siberia is being **sheeted home** to climate change. ...

I find the [definitions](http://dictionary.babylon-software.com/to_sheet_home/):

> to **sheet home**
>   (naut.), to haul upon a sheet until the sail is as flat, and the clew as near the wind, as possible...
>
> To haul the sheets of a sail home to the block on the yard-arm.

Is the ABC's usage some metaphor on the nautical meaning?

Comment: I suspect the term is an Aussieism.

Comment: A nautical expression, now common Australian usage.  Until recently all immigrants arrived by ship, and the Marine Corp provided much of the early administration.  'Sheeted home' in Australian usage suggests 'conclusively attributed'.  The nautical sense is about finality or conclusion - all the sails are sheeted home (tied down) there's nothing to do until the wind or the ship's heading changes.  A form that bridges those senses might be: "The debate about the cause of the ... has been sheeted home, we now believe it is ....."  I'll scout for similar examples from 19th Century Australia.

Comment: @JohnMack You should make an answer out of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in a dictionary. It's right there in the Merriam Webster, well, fifth definition of *sheet*, second sub-definition. Unfortunately, there's no examples in there.

> *sheet home 2* : to fix the responsibility for :  bring home to one [- Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sheet)

Thus, it's not a metaphor on the nautical meaning but a standalone meaning. They are blaming the climate change for the anthrax outbreak. Likely due to warming up the bacteria from hibernation.

Comment: John Mack's comment suggests that the term, even in this sense, **IS** a nautical metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expression meaning "to define responsibility" or to make someone responsible for an action, usually found in business, especially in Australia or in UK

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Can you provide sources for your answer? This site strives to provide objective answers. Have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about good answers.